# how to add clinker.47deg.com to my sonatype Nexus repositories?

Tags: maven, proxy, sonatype

[image]

This is my config,but the status always show "Remote Connection Pending"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modify the version to **2.11**,
and everything gonna be all right.